# unrecognized Do loop error in mapbasic

Tags: mapbasic

unrecognized command do is occurring when i am trying to use below code in mapbasic window. can anyone help me how to fix it although syntaz is correct

```
fetch first from t1

Do while Not EOT(t1) 
    'Do this with table t1 
    fetch Next from t1 
Loop
```

Comment: The syntax looks ok, have you got any other code running before this? Is `t1` a table name, string variable or alias variable?

Comment: yes i am printing table t1 row count its printing fine but when i use any loop like for next, do while its giving error unrecognized command

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use loops in the MapBasic Window. You need to download the stand-alone [Mapbasic](http://www.pbinsight.com/support/product-downloads/for/mapbasic) program and compile your code into an application.

For simple code you should be able to migrate from the MapBasic Window to MapBasic Application with very few, if any, changes, so it shouldn't be too daunting.